# While handling interrupt signal in 'http_listener.h' gives segmentation fault using Microsoft CppRestSdk

Tags: github, cpprest-sdk

I am using 'https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk' v2.8 and trying to handle interrupt signal but 'cpprest/http_listener.h' gives segmentation fault.
If I comment out line no 3( #include <cpprest/http_listener.h>) server gets stop without any segmentation fault.

[image]

My code snippet is as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    std::wcout<<"Exiting the program... ::" << signal << std::endl;    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Registring a signal handler to prevent abrupt exits
    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    try {
        while (true);   
    }
    catch (std::exception const & e) {
        std::wcout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }  
    
    return 0;
}
```

Versions used : 
OS - Linux 16.04 
CPP REST version - 2.8 
G++ version - 7.5.0

Command to compile above code snippet - `g++ test.cpp -o spike_op1 -lcpprest -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread`

So there is issue in cpprest/http_listener.h file, does anyone have it's solution?